# How to add a new Category to Form Designer in Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

[image: Form Designer with highlighted category]

In the Sitecore Forms Designer there are four predetermined categories for elements for your form.

- Basic
- Lists
- Security
- Structure

I've looked everywhere and even added a folder in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types` and added my new field types into this folder, but it doesn't work that way, from what I can tell.

How can I create a new category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)
You need to keep your category under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types` in `master` database.

2)
But you also need to add some more items in `core` database.

2a)
You need to duplicate DraggableBasic and ExpanderBasic items in `core` database that you can find under `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Pages/FormDesigner/PageSettings/InfoTabControl/Design/PageSettings`.

Name them accordingly Draggable{your_category_name} and Expander{your_category_name}.

Change value in StaticData field in Drabbable item to id of your category created in master database under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types`:

[image]

so in my case it was like this:

[image]

Also change HeaderText field in Expander item according to your desired category name:
[image]

2b)
You need to add these newly created expander and draggable items in the Design tab shared renderings.

Navigate to `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Pages/FormDesigner/PageSettings/InfoTabControl/Design` item and turn on showing Raw values.
Scroll down to Renderings field (Shared renderings). If you cannot see it, turn on also showing Standard fields:

[image]

Copy the value to Notepad or any other editor and format it a bit to be more readable.

Duplicate two entries related to ExpanderBasic and rename them accordingly to your setup. For me it was ExpanderAdvanced ;)

I have duplicated these renderings:

```
<r uid="{ED3AE365-02C5-4B10-8ECF-E2283DEC668B}" p:after="r[@uid='{6B1B70A9-6236-4447-B4B3-5F6082A61B8B}']" s:id="{1CA7EB02-74E0-42F9-B8C9-32E62FD505BD}" s:par="Id=ExpanderBasic" s:ph="" />

<r uid="{85DEAD48-AC75-4B74-AAFB-079D379E0C1B}" p:after="r[@uid='{F4B0C881-F46E-47BB-B76B-C3219BF16D4A}']" s:id="{E3DDC819-50A5-477A-A3A3-4CDCF3C7B5A4}" s:par="Id=DraggableBasic" s:ph="ExpanderBasic.Body" />
```

and placed my duplicated renderings right after them and moved id in p:after accordingly:

[image]

Copy or replace all rendering elements back to the field according to your changes.

You can you use https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx with Uppcase turned on to generate guids for your newly created renderings or Visual Studio :)

This is result:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I used Sitecore Rocks (since it's a SPEAK application) to add the two renderings to the presentation details.  But end result is the same.